# NextJS page with getServerSideProps is loading slowly

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I have a dynamic routed page in my NextJS app. It has only one API call. I placed this API call inside getServerSideProps. My page is taking about 7 seconds to load.

The website is hosted at Vercel.

In the Postman the same API call is taking 2 seconds.

Link to the page:
https://investt.in/mutual-funds/sbi-focused-equity-fund-direct-plan-growth

getServerSideProps code:

```
  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const fund = context.params.fund;
  var fundPageResult = {};
  var titleFundResult = {};
  const titleCase = async (str) => {
    var str1 = await str.replace(/-/g, " ");

    var splitStr = await str1.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
      splitStr[i] =
        splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
    }
    var splitStr1 = await splitStr.join(" ");
    var splitStr2 = splitStr1
      .replace(/Sbi/g, "SBI")
      .replace(/ Sp /g, " S&P ")
      .replace(/Lt /g, "L&T ");

    return splitStr2;
  };

  async function apiRequest(url) {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    if (resp.ok) {
      return resp.json();
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }
  const fundPageRes = apiRequest(
    `https://localhost:8000/fundpage/?name=${fund}`
  );

  const titleFund = titleCase(fund);

  await Promise.all([fundPageRes, titleFund])
    .then(([fundPageResul, titleFundResul]) => {
      fundPageResult = fundPageResul;
      titleFundResult = titleFundResul;
    })
    .catch((e) => {});

  return {
    props: {
      fund: fund,
      titleFund: titleFundResult,
      avggReturnsResult: fundPageResult["average"],
    },
  };
}
```

How can I reduce this loading time?

Comment: Can you share link for the page?

Comment: Can you also share your `getServerSideProps` code? How long does the API call take if you make the request in Postman?

Comment: I have updated the question with link to the page and added getServerSideProps code.
In the Postman the API call is taking 2 seconds.

Comment: The `replace`, `toLowerCase` and `splitStr` functions are not asynchronous, you shouldn't be using `await` on them. The `titleCase` function doesn't not need to be `async`.

Comment: Can you also share the code for the `/fundpage?name=${fund}` endpoint? That's most likely the cause for the long TTFB.

Comment: Code for /fundpage?name=${fund} endpoint

https://codeshare.io/78pYk1